# OCaml Format: how to indent the automatic line breaks

Tags: formatting, ocaml

I'm trying to use OCaml's [Format](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) module to pretty print some structures. According to the [tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/format.html), I just need to use boxes and specify break points where it is appropriate to have new lines. However, I'm unable to get the indentation right.

For example:

```
# open Format;;
# fprintf std_formatter "bar =  foo(@[<hv 1>lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,@ lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,@ lkjj: lkjlk@])";;
bar =  foo(
lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
 lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
 lkjj: lkjlk)
- : unit = ()
```

However, I'm expecting to get:

```
bar =  foo(lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
            lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
            lkjj: lkjlk)
```

How do I get it to indent the arguments correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the source of your problem is the maximum indentation limit; if your code begins with a `Format.set_margin 20` then it has the side-effect of also setting the maximum indentation limit to 10.

This means that boxes which should have been opened with an indentation greater than 10 are pushed to a new line and are opened with an indentation of 0.

In other words,

```
 Format.set_margin 20;;
 Format.printf "bar =  foo(@[<hv 1>lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,@ lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,@ lkjj: lkjlk,@ aze: azeioajze@])@.";;
```

yields:

```
bar =  foo(
lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
lkjj: lkjlk)
```

Setting the maximum indentation limit to 11 after setting the margin partially fixes the issue:

```
 Format.set_margin 20; Format.set_max_indent 11; 
 Format.printf "bar =  foo(@[<hv 1>lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,@ lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,@ lkjj: lkjlk,@ aze: azeioajze@])@.";;
```

yields

```
bar =  foo(lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
           lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
           lkjj: lkjlk)
```

In other words, the `hv` box was opened without needing a line break; but the indentation was not increased.

Setting max_indent to a value between 12 and 18

```
 Format.set_margin 20; Format.set_max_indent 12; 
 Format.printf "bar =  foo(@[<hv 1>lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,@ lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,@ lkjj: lkjlk,@ aze: azeioajze@])@.";;
```

completely fixes this issue:

```
bar = foo(lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
           lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
           lkjj: lkjlk)
```

The take-away message here is probably that you should alway set the margin and the maximum indentation limit at the same time (and in *this* order ).

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce. I get this:

```
# Format.fprintf Format.std_formatter "bar =  foo(@[<hv 1>lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,@ lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,@ lkjj: lkjlk,@ aze: azeioajze@])";;
bar =  foo(lkjlkjlkj: lkjlkjlkj,
            lkjlkjlkjlj: lkjlkjlkjlkj,
            lkjj: lkjlk,
            aze: azeioajze)- : unit = ()
```

Which is expected. Opening a box doesn't cause a cut, so if you want a newline after `foo(`, you should write `@[<hv>@,`.

Comment: Ah yes, that was a mistake in the expected output. I corrected it.